# Custom Event Type in angular bootstrap calendar

Tags: angularjs, calendar

https://github.com/mattlewis92/angular-bootstrap-calendar

In the [examples](http://mattlewis92.github.io/angular-bootstrap-calendar/#?example=kitchen-sink) event.type is `INFO, WARNING` etc. Can I add custom event types? I would like the event types to be dynamic.

Comment: This is here at the request of the project author that support questions be asked here.

Answer (score 1):

I do not believe that you can have custom event types but I am not 100% sure. The event type attribute is required and can be 6 different types:

```
type: 'info', // The type of the event (determines its color). Can be important, warning, info, inverse, success or special
```

The type of event only determines the color though so I am not sure why you would need a custom type. You can already customize your event with your personal information. And then tag it as a certain type for the color effect.

Comment: Thanks, I have tried doing custom types and it seems to work I just need to provide my own css. What I don't know is if it is used for anything other than color.

Comment: Yeah, from the documentation it looks like it was just for color but I do not know. Glad you were able to make custom events. Good luck.